# Why does env cause Python Popen to hang?

Tags: python, subprocess

**Edit:** I've figured out that this problem is being caused by something to do with env. If I remove env from the below, all works well.

I've got a bit of a classic Python `Popen` problem.

Below is the code I'm using to create an async iterator from a `Popen` call. For the most part, it works. However, sometimes it gets deadlocked; it does this particularly often when run in the same process as a `uvicorn` server.

```py
import os
import subprocess
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
from typing import IO, AsyncIterator, Dict, Iterable, Optional, Tuple
from enum import Enum, IntEnum
import sys


class StdFd(IntEnum):
    stdout = 0
    stderr = 1
    stdeof = 2

def read_fd(pipe :  IO[bytes], queue : Queue[Tuple[StdFd, bytes]], fd : Optional[StdFd] = StdFd.stdout):
    try:
        with pipe:
            for line in iter(pipe.readline, b""):
                queue.put((fd, line))
    finally:
        queue.put((StdFd.stdeof, b""))

async def call_with_env(cmd : Iterable[str], *, env : Dict[str, str])->AsyncIterator[Tuple[StdFd, bytes]]:
    
    queue : Queue[Tuple[StdFd, bytes]] = Queue()
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
        env=env,
    )
   
    Thread(target=read_fd, args=[process.stdout, queue, StdFd.stdout]).start()
    Thread(target=read_fd, args=[process.stderr, queue, StdFd.stderr]).start()
    
    hits = 0
    while hits < 2:
        try:
            next = queue.get(block=False)
            
            if next[0] == StdFd.stdeof:
                hits += 1
                continue
        
            yield next
        except Exception:
            continue
        
    yield (StdFd.stdeof, b"")
```

I've tried flushing all number of things. That hasn't yet made a difference. What can check next?

I also get the same behavior when calling `process.communicate()`, though this wouldn't produce the desired behavior anyways.

The Python version is 3.10.10. I run into the same behavior with `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec`.

Comment: Does it work if you put `env=env.copy()`?

Comment: Don't use a `with` statement in `read_fd`. Generally, you aren't responsible for closing something you didn't open.